# Sharing PHP classes across multiple servers

Tags: php, web-services, oop, rest, distributed

Lets assume one has two servers, one is used for frontend stuff (one application) the other is used for backend stuff (the other application). The frontend server delivers data through a webserver to the backend server.

Furthermore, the two applications use classes (object instances) to communicate. So, to send data about foo from one to another, foo is filled with values, serialized and send to the other party. It would then be deserialized and an instance of the same class would then be filled with the incoming data.

What's the best way to have a consistent architecture for these classes? foo is the same on both sides. Should one have only one file foo.php and distribute it while deploying? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I have to say this seems a little sloppy to me. Would in not be better to transfer the data to populate the object in XML(/JSON/whatever)?

Comment: Well, you need the class on both sides to work with. So, for convience reasons and for easier debugging I don't want to create objects "on the fly". I would like to have the blueprint of it on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it on a shared filesystem seems like an easy way to solve the problem. The approach I've taken in the past is to define a hierarchy of include directories with different replication scope (using rsync to replicate) - although in some cases a managed deployment is required (but this does not preclude the use of rsync as a failsafe).

e.g. the first directory on the include path is '.' and replicated across all nodes in the environment (where environment is develpoment / test / live), then one which is not replicated (i.e. unique to that node), then one which is replicated across equivalent nodes for the same application/environment, then one which is replicated across the environment, then one which is replicated across all systems.

Comment: So, having a common codebase for the two applications which are then deployed with whatever method seems like the best approach. I am using "ant" at the moment. rsync is a nice idea.